# Variable Scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {

    Variable: 1, 

    Name: function() {
      Variable  += 1;
    }

   return this.Variable
}

var obj = {

    Name: function() {
      var Variable = 1;
      Variable  += 1;
    }

   return Variable
}
```

1. Now what is the difference between these two?
2. Does these two give
       different outputs.

Comment: this is invalid code... ?

Comment: Neither of these are valid javascript...

Comment: @Dominic Barnes: Why this is invalid code?

Comment: In your second example, it is set to `1` each time and added with `1`, i.e. always returning `2` (if you put the `return` correctly, that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what you want...

```
function wrapperFunction()
{
    var Obj = {
        variable: 1,
        ....
    };
    return Obj ;
}
```

You can try also wrapping the entire object inside of a function. Then use the function to return a new instance each time the wrapping function is called.

Answer (score 3):

1) The difference is that the definition of `Variable` variable is in different location.

2) No, they have the same output: output nothing and give you error.

=== Update for your comment (Why this is invalid code?) ===

Because you cannot `return` inside an object literal.

ie.

```
{ return "something" }
```

is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Objects don't return.  That's something functions do.  You're lacking a Closure.

Answer (score 2):

Your script has a lot of nonsense;

in the first case, you declare a variable "Variable" member of the object.

```
 var obj = {

        Variable: 1,

    }
```

and you use a variable "Variable" registered in global:

```
var obj = { 
    Name: function() {
      Variable  += 1;
    }
}
```

You cannot use return in your object.

```
var obj = {

   return Variable
}
```